# MySQL: How to write query that takes average of sums of numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

**QUESTION:** Return for each artist the average number of tracks on their albums.
Given:

artist(id, name)

album(id, title)

artist_album(artist_id, album_id)

track (track_title, album_id, num)

---

I want a table that shows the artist name and their average number of tracks on their album, meaning that an artist can have multiple albums with multiple songs in each album, and we need the average number of tracks from all the albums.

```
SELECT artist.name, COUNT(track_title) as averageTracks
FROM artist
    JOIN track
    ON track.album_id = artist_album.album_id
    JOIN artist_album
    ON artist_album.artist_id = artist.id
GROUP BY artist.name
HAVING AVG(averageTracks);
```

Instead of giving me the average number of tracks, take for example Bob Marley might have 13 songs total from 4 different albums, it should give me 3.25, but in this case it gives me 13 instead. So I'm not sure where the AVG() method goes.

Comment: Use `count(*)/count(distinct artist_album.album_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually closer than you might think.  The average number of tracks is the total number of tracks divided by the number of albums.  You can get this as:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(*) * 1.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT aa.album_id) as averageTracks
FROM artist a JOIN
     artist_album aa
     ON aa.artist_id = a.id JOIN
     track t
     ON t.album_id = aa.album_id
GROUP BY a.name;
```

Of course, your query will not work because the join conditions are out of sequence with the table definitions.

Your `HAVING AVG(averageTracks)` *filters* the results.  It does not change the calculations in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks! one small issue though, it seems to round the numbers by default for some reason. Given the Bob Marley example, it rounds the 3.25 to a 3. Do you know why its doing that?

Comment: @yushi . . . some databases do integer division.  However, MySQL should result in a real number.  You can multiply by 1.0 so you get the fractional part.

Comment: You didn't put an alias on `JOIN artist_album` as `JOIN artist_album as aa` . Second: in the field list `COUNT(DISTINCT a.album_id)` should be `COUNT(DISTINCT aa.album_id)` using the `aa` alias of `artist_album`